# If both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are one to one functions and $g(f(x))= f(g(x)) = x$, why does this prove they are inverse of each other?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are one to one functions and $g(f(x)) = f(g(x)) = x$ why does this prove they are inverse of each other? I understand function composition but the way they overlap confuses the hell out of me. Can anyone who answers the question also guide me into being able to read these function compositions without getting confused with the overlapping?

Comment: How would you define an inverse function?

Comment: You need to have an example in hand. Take $\sin:[0,\pi/2]\to[0,1]$ and $\arcsin:[0,1]\to[0,\pi/2]$. Note that the domains and codomains *must* be mentioned. And remember that “arcsin” means “the angle whose sine is”. And remember also that the defining relations must hold for $all$ $x$ in the respective domain.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the term "inverse function" means. You put $3$ into $f$ and get $95$; you put $95$ into the inverse of $f$ and get $3.$ And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Simply because, by definition: $$f^{-1}(f(x))=x$$ and $$f(f^{-1}(x))=x$$

For example, if $f(x)=y$, then $f^{-1}(y)=x$

Comment: Idk I'm confused but if g(x) equaled a for example and f(x) equaled a. Then f(b) equals x and g(a) equals x. With that in mind it doesn't show that they see ninverse of each other since x has to be a in g with it outputing b.